# Flex FileReference.browse() opens a save dialog - NOT an open dialog

Tags: apache-flex, filereference

IE will open an open dialog but FireFox 12 with Flash plug-in 11.2.202.235 opens a save dialog.

This happens for 2 other co-workers but not for anyone else - any ideas?

Comment: Firefox opens the save dialog. :')

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to 10.1 fixed the problem.
Go here to get it:
http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html